# Un recoginised keyword near like when i use Not Like in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

i am trying to use not like in my sql query but it gives me error .
please help.

```
SELECT word FROM school WHERE level  LIKE '%level%' AND NOT LIKE '%llevel%'
```

Comment: `WHERE level  LIKE '%level%' AND level   NOT LIKE '%llevel%'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USe column name level  for both condition.

```
      SELECT word FROM school WHERE level  LIKE '%level%' AND level  NOT LIKE '%llevel%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You've missed `level` column name in second condition:

```
SELECT word FROM school WHERE level  LIKE '%level%' AND level NOT LIKE '%llevel%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `level` before the `NOT LIKE`

```
SELECT word FROM school WHERE level  LIKE '%level%' AND level NOT LIKE '%llevel%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT word
FROM school
WHERE level REGEXP '%[^l]level%'
```

This assumes that the matches you want are of the form of at least a single character followed by `level`, followed by zero or more characters.  Your original query implies this to be the case.

Comment: Sql doesn't recognise REGEXP

Comment: @user3518835 But MySQL does, check the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html) for yourself.